# HTML5 audio to start playing from anywhere even when the whole file is not loaded

Tags: audio-streaming, audiojs

I'm using [audio.js](http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/) on my page to play mp3s.
Some of the mp3s are over 100MB in size.
For example : I have a 124 MB mp3 file which doesn't load fully - the loader is loading the file slowly due to a slow internet connection. But when I click on the player-bar in the middle, I want it to start playing from there. Is that possible in HTML5 / audiojs ?

Comment: mp3 has split format for playing not need to load all file then play you can play during of loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server needs to support range requests, which allows the client to specify specific content ranges that it needs.  Once you have configured your server, any client-side code that is built to take advantage of this feature will start working.

You can find an example here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8507991/362536