# LibAV dealing with 'moov' atom at the end of the file

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, libav, mpeg

I am trying to figure out how to use `libav` to receive streaming mp4 that contains `moov` atom at the end of a file. I found that, `libav` has problems decoding such files from https://d.tube. To identify this problem, I have used `AtomicParsley` to see the position of `moov`atom. Furthermore, I have tested with `qt-faststart`. The problematic files processed with `qt-faststart` have no problem with `libav` at all.

I also looked into how browsers handle this kind of file as mentioned in [how HTML5 video handle video with moov atom at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330575/how-html5-video-handle-video-with-moov-atom-at-the-end). I tried download the first and the last chunk of a file to check first before streaming, but `avformat_open_input()` cannot open only the last chunk of the file. I think it needs some information from other atoms as well.

So, I would like to ask if anyone knows that `libav` can somehow handle this problem.