# Audio problems in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio

I'm trying to develop an HTML5 game. To this end I have the PHP built-in server running on my local machine to work on, then I "compile" it (combine/minify JS files, minify CSS, etc) and upload them to the production server.

I've run into an issue with the sound effects. For some reason, Chrome won't recognise that it has reached the end of the sound, and therefore will get stuck in a "buffering" state. This is in spite of a valid `Content-Length` header. IE and Firefox don't seem to have this problem. It also affects the `loop` attribute, and it also fails to fire `ended` events.

These problems are only present on the PHP built-in server. It works fine in production. What am I missing?

---

EDIT: Here's an example request/response on the PHP server:

```text
GET /bin/aud/rightwhereiwantyou.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.0.110:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
Accept: */*
Referer: http://10.0.0.110:8000/snake.php
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Range: bytes=0-

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: 10.0.0.110:8000
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.13
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Content-Length: 1685058
```

Comment: Can you show a packet trace?  I suspect you're missing a `Content-Type` header, or having trouble with range requests.

Comment: See edit, I've added a sample request/response.

Comment: Hmmm, what's the difference between this and the one that works?

Comment: The one that works has things like `ETag`... and a `Content-Range` header. Maybe that's the thing I'm missing...

Comment: Nope, just added the `Content-Range` header and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately not - as shown in the sample this is hosted on my local machine, and I don't have the ability to open it up to outside users.

Comment: If you could upload an actual packet capture, that might be helpful.  Otherwise, I'm not sure what to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess is that Chrome is accepting a partial content response (a byte range), since the MP3 file could be large and you might want to be streaming it instead.

Have you tried adding the `Accept-Ranges` and `Content-Range` headers to your response? See the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293687/sample-http-range-request-session) question for an example.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=111281) with Google Chrome.