# "Range:" http header causes hang in ColdFusion app

Tags: coldfusion, http-headers, timeout, railo

Whenever I add the "range" header in a HTTP request for a .cfm or .cfc file on my server, I get a timeout. The server simply does not respond.

To debug, I created a blank file called "/signup/test.cfm" on my server. It contains nothing. Next, I make a normal request and an edited request for the file:

```
Request:
GET /signup/test.cfm HTTP/1.1
Host: site.com

Response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Request:
GET /signup/test.cfm HTTP/1.1
Host: site.com
Range: bytes=0-40960

Response:
timeout in transmission from site.com
```

If I include the Range header in a request to a static file, there is no problem.

What could be causing this, and how do I debug it? The file I am requesting is empty, so no code should be executing. Application.cfc is empty. Since I assume no code is executing, does this mean that it is a server configuration problem?

EDIT: By adding a  tag to my script, I have confirmed that it *does* execute the ColdFusion code. The response is just never sent back to me.

Comment: Which web server are you using? Can you show us how you are adding the range header?

Comment: @Miguel-F Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5

Comment: @Miguel-F I am adding the range header through a proxy called "Burp Suite" which can edit requests on the fly, though I can replicate it with other tools.

Comment: Could the issue be that you are requesting an empty file (ie. 0 bytes)? Can you try the request after modifying your .cfm file to have some content, even if it is only static content?

Comment: Just tried it with CF9 and Apache 2.2 and I cannot replicate this on my environment. The range header is having no effect on the response

Comment: @Miguel-F I have now tried adding static content to the file. The issue remains.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I was just curious. [I found this similar discussion](http://house-of-fusion.10909.n7.nabble.com/cfheader-Content-Range-td97384.html). Not sure why you are getting a timeout. Seems like ColdFusion might just send the contents without honoring the range, but not timeout. Is the request getting to ColdFusion or stopping at IIS?

Comment: @Miguel-F Yes, this is what I expect, too. I already searched a lot both on here and Google, and it seems like nobody else has the issue. Does any other file than application.cfc exist which might be executing code on each request? Maybe such a file could be causing this.

Comment: Yes, perhaps, depending on your configuration. Note that the file "Application.cfc" must start with a capital "A". Can you successfully browse to a .cfm file in that same folder without the range header? If so, view the contents of the response and it's headers to see that it is what you are expecting.

Comment: @Miguel-F Yes, I can do this without the range header. The static text I put in the file is displayed. The whole site is fully functional as expected - the only problem is when the range header is sent.

Comment: @Miguel-F I have tried something new now. If I make the test.cfm file write to a file, it successfully does this *even though the server times out*! This means that the CF code is running, but no response is returned. Does this give you any new ideas?

Comment: Well that verifies the request is getting through to ColdFusion. What version of ColdFusion are you running? What Java server (JRun, Apache, etc.)? Sorry I don't really have an answer just trying to help debug.

Comment: @Miguel-F I appreciate it. CF version: 9.0.0.1. I am using Railo.

Comment: Okay, I will see if I can find anything. By the way, I think I found a decent post on how to implement this in ColdFusion assuming we can get it to respond. It includes a function to process the Range request: [Media Delivery to iPhones and iPads](http://rickawd.tumblr.com/post/15343511500/media-delivery-to-iphones-and-ipads)

Comment: Well I was trying to move our discussion to chat but apparently you don't have enough rep yet. Geez!! Anyway, I see that [Railo has added an attribute to the cfcontent tag to support the range header](https://github.com/getrailo/railo/wiki/Enhanced_Tags#wiki-cfcontent). Nice! I also found that some [issues with this functionality have been patched](http://www.getrailo.org/index.cfm/download/history/). What version of Railo are you on?

Comment: I am running Railo 3.3.1.000. The cfcontent tag option does not fix my issue. I do not need to support the range header fully, by the way, I simply need to return a normal 200 response.

Comment: @Miguel-F If I add the tag <cfabort showerror="any message"> to the bottom of my script, it all runs and outputs, and then the railo error is shown at the bottom. So it seems like I need some way to "flush" the output out by the end of a request..

Comment: Interesting... That's why earlier I had you put some content in your empty file to see if having actual content made this work. There is a `cfflush` tag but not sure that will help. `cfcontent` tag maybe? But I think you said you already tried that.

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the cf parser doesn't work with ranged requests while the static file handler does.

Range is for fetching part of content and subsequently fetching more later. E.g. Video file streaming or download continuation. Not something easily handled by a script handler as the request is meant to be returned all at once.

Here's a stackoverflow with a sample range request to show how this works
[Sample http range request session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293687/sample-http-range-request-session)