# Streaming audio from webserver

Tags: python, ios, audio, streaming

I'm creating a simple app that can play audio files (currently only mp3 files) located on a webserver.

Currently, I'm using Python's SimpleHTTPServer server side, and the AVAudioPlayer for iOS.

It sort of works, since the file is streamed over HTTP instead of just being downloaded from the webserver. But I often experience that the playback of a file is suddenly restarted.

I'm considering using another method of streaming, eg. RTMP, but on the other hand I want to keep things simple. I'm wondering if another HTTP server might do the trick? Any other experiences/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when the playback is restarted?  Print the HTTP URLs on the server. Does the player start from `index=0`, go to `index=4000`, then back to `index=0` again?

Comment: Is the index= a certain protocol? I tried logging using Charles, and it does not report that the client makes such requests. It just shows a request to the plain url, eg. http://localhost:3000/song.mp3

Comment: I just made up `index=123`.  Also log the HTTP headers, there might be an `Accept-Ranges` value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293687/sample-http-range-request-session