# Ranged Response Flow in Phoenix/Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How can I implement the flow in the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293687/sample-http-range-request-session) on Phoenix? At first I thought I had to use `Conn.send_chunked` and `Conn.chunk` but I am starting to realize I will be getting many requests instead of me sending a various responses.

Answer (score 2):

If anybody is interested, this is my solution. Talks correctly to video players, and also handles normal files.

```
[range_start, range_end] = 
    if Enum.empty?(Conn.get_req_header(conn, "range")) do
      [0, file.content_length - 1]  
    else
      [rn] = Conn.get_req_header(conn, "range")

      res = Regex.run(~r/bytes=([0-9]+)-([0-9])?/, rn)
      default_end = Integer.to_string(file.content_length - 1)

      {range_start, _} = res |> Enum.at(1) |> Integer.parse
      {range_end, _} = res |> Enum.at(2, default_end) |> Integer.parse

      [range_start, range_end]
    end

    content_length = range_end - range_start + 1

    conn = conn
      |> Conn.put_resp_content_type(file.content_type)
      |> Conn.put_resp_header("content-length", Integer.to_string(content_length))
      |> Conn.put_resp_header("accept-ranges", "bytes")
      |> Conn.put_resp_header("content-disposition", ~s(inline; filename="#{file.filename}"))
      |> Conn.put_resp_header("content-range", "bytes #{range_start}-#{range_end}/#{file.content_length}")
      |> Conn.send_file(206, "#{files_path}/#{id}", range_start, content_length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting your solution Cristian! I never would've figured this out otherwise...

For any Elixir newbies such as myself who run across this and can't *quite* get the above snippet to work, here's my full controller method:

```
def load_song(conn, params) do
  filename = List.first(params["song"])
  file_path = "priv/static/sounds/#{filename}"
  {:ok, stats} = File.stat(file_path)
  filesize = stats.size

  [range_start, range_end] =
      if Enum.empty?(Plug.Conn.get_req_header(conn, "range")) do
        [0, filesize - 1]
      else
        [rn] = Plug.Conn.get_req_header(conn, "range")

        res = Regex.run(~r/bytes=([0-9]+)-([0-9])?/, rn)
        default_end = Integer.to_string(filesize - 2)

        {range_start, _} = res |> Enum.at(1) |> Integer.parse
        {range_end, _} = res |> Enum.at(2, default_end) |> Integer.parse

        [range_start, range_end]
      end

  content_length = range_end - range_start + 2

  conn
    |> Plug.Conn.put_resp_content_type("audio/mpeg")
    |> Plug.Conn.put_resp_header("content-length", Integer.to_string(content_length))
    |> Plug.Conn.put_resp_header("accept-ranges", "bytes")
    |> Plug.Conn.put_resp_header("content-disposition", ~s(inline; filename="#{filename}"))
    |> Plug.Conn.put_resp_header("content-range", "bytes #{range_start}-#{range_end}/#{filesize}")
    |> Plug.Conn.send_file(206, file_path, range_start, content_length)
end
```

I've learned since about some basic Elixir features like aliasing that would've simplified this, and I'm guessing some other coding choices are a little un-idiomatic, but the above show work as a "drop in" method for your controller.

Comment: Glad it helped, I spend a whole afternoon figuring it out, I hope other can get it done quicker with the answer. I see you changed the math a little.

Comment: Oops, I may have done that accidentally. I'm used to working at higher levels of abstraction than raw bytes, so I was a little uncertain figuring out content length and file size :)

I'll have to do some experiments this afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a plug for this called plug_range, it will catch every range request and serve them.
It is still a work in progress to follow the RFC, but it might comes in handy until then.

[PlugRange](https://github.com/TheSquad/plug_range)