# Byte Serving (Range Request) Workflow

Tags: http-headers, webserver, rfc

My understanding of the [HTTP 1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233)RFC that outlines ranges is that when the server response has a header of `Accept-Ranges`, the client can make a range request, as outlined well in this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving)

My confusion is how does the client initiate the processes?

1. Does the client assume the server accepts ranges, and sends a request for a partial range?
2. Or does the client begin by checking if the server accepts ranges first?

This [StackOverflow] [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8507991/1158977) answer does a good job of explaining it, but the comments below it make it confusing again

If it's `2` then does the initial request have the filename? Or is that not specified in the RFC?

Answer (score 0):

According to [section 2.3 of RFC7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-2.3) :

> The "Accept-Ranges" header field **allows a server to indicate that it
> supports range requests** for the target resource.

> [...]

> An origin server that supports byte-range requests for a given target
> resource MAY send

> Accept-Ranges: bytes

> to indicate what range units are supported.  **A client MAY generate
> range requests without having received this header field** for the
> resource involved.

The answer to your question is **both**. A client can wait to check if the server support range request or he can generate a range requests without having received this header field.